# Seekbar thumb image gets cut off

Tags: android, android-layout

I have setup a seekbar with a custom thumb image. The initial image is set by XML file and shows fine no cut off. When I make change to image the image gets cut off on the bottom. The seekbar XML is loaded into a framelayout. Seekbar works fine but movement runs past view. So the when I run to max the top gets cut off and when I rum to minimum the bottom gets cut. Both  images are the same size.

Here is the initial XML

```
       <SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBarr"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="230dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/mastersliderback"
    android:rotation="270"
    android:thumb="@drawable/imgsliderred70" />
```

here is the code that loads new image.

```
    Drawable thumb1 = getResources().getDrawable(       R.drawable.imgsliderred70_rate);
    SliderRed.setThumb(thumb1);
```

Comment: Hello there, did you find what caused it?

Answer (score 4):

I found some additional information on the issue.It was not the image size as I thought but the offset and padding. 
Here is a the changes I made and the image is no longer clipped.

```
       <SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBarr"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="230dp"
    android:paddingLeft="35dp"
    android:paddingRight="35dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/mastersliderback"
    android:rotation="270"
    android:thumb="@drawable/imgsliderred70"
    android:thumbOffset="8dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `gradle.build` under root directory
2. Right-click the line that goes like this: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'`
3. And press the `sync now` option (if no such option exists then try a different answer)
4. Press the blue buttons to the left on both pop-up screens (if there are any)
5. Wait for the installations to finish
6. Rebuild the project

And just like magic it suddenly works